# How to add text before and after selection in Sublime Text?

Tags: text, sublimetext2

How can I make a shortcut, so that my selected text is wrapped with special characters?

For example:

For teaching HTML, I'd like to show some tags in plain text. When selecting `span` I'd like to wrap the selection with `&lt;` and `&gt;`.

How can I do this?

Comment: are you only wrapping `span`, or do you want it to work with any tag?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Create a snippet in your User directory `tag.sublime-snippet`:

```
<snippet>
<content><![CDATA[
&lt;$0$SELECTION&gt;
]]></content>
</snippet>
```

Save and make a new key binding in your User keybindings

```
    { "keys": ["ctrl+t"], "command": "insert_snippet", "args": { "name": "Packages/User/tag.sublime-snippet" } },
```

Though the best way to do this is to simply use Search and replace the left `<` to `&lt;` and then `>` to `&gt;`

Comment: Using it everyday :) Thanks again!

Comment: @Milkmannetje glad this works for you, make sure to upvote and accept the answer if it answers the question, that will help others see that it works as well as helps indexing the page in search results.

Answer (score 1):

Might be a bit overkill for what you are trying to do, but take a look at [BracketHighlighter](https://github.com/facelessuser/BracketHighlighter). Specifically, the [bracket wrapping](https://github.com/facelessuser/BracketHighlighter#bracket-wrapping-plugin) functionality. Will take some configuration on your part, but saves you the trouble of writing your own plugin.